# TopoJSON in Leaflet, via Omnivore: reading properties

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, topojson

While following along a [tutorial on choropleth maps in Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) I realized that a Shapefile > GeoJSON conversion generated a very large file. TopoJSON proved a better alternative, except for being unable to access the properties for each geometry. I merged data from https://github.com/centraldedados/violencia-domestica into a [TopoJSON file converted from a Shapefile](http://view-source:http://www.audiovisualcode.net/tmp/dgai_vd_2009_2014/dgai_violencia_domestica_2008_2014.topo.json), structured like so:

```js
{
  "transform": {
    "scale": [
      0.0025081552497290688,
      0.0012125352320998587
    ],
    "translate": [
      -31.26818656921381,
      30.03017616271984
    ]
  },
  "objects": {"PRT_adm1": {
    "geometries": [
      {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "arcs": [[
          0,
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4
        ]],
        "properties": {
          "ENGTYPE_1": "District",
          "ISO": "PRT",
          "NL_NAME_1": null,
          "HASC_1": "PT.EV",
          "ID_0": 182,
          "NAME_0": "Portugal",
          "TYPE_1": "Distrito",
          "ID_1": 1,
          "NAME_1": "Évora",
          "CCN_1": 0,
          "CCA_1": null,
          "dgai_violencia_domestica_2008_2014": {
            "Valores": [
              {
                "Ano": "2009",
                "Entidade": [
                  {"GNR": "216"},
                  {"PSP": "171"}
                ]
              },
              {
                "Ano": "2010",
                "Entidade": [
                  {"GNR": "247"},
                  {"PSP": "162"}
                ]
              },
              {
                "Ano": "2011",
                "Entidade": [
                  {"GNR": "248"},
                  {"PSP": "181"}
                ]
              },
              {
                "Ano": "2012",
                "Entidade": [
                  {"GNR": "277"},
                  {"PSP": "150"}
                ]
              },
              {
                "Ano": "2013",
                "Entidade": [
                  {"GNR": "207"},
                  {"PSP": "169"}
                ]
              },
              {
                "Ano": "2014",
                "Entidade": [
                  {"GNR": "226"},
                  {"PSP": "137"}
                ]
              }
            ],
            "Distrito": "Évora",
            "Factor_amostra": 0.020521270111203194,
            "Somatorio_amostra": 2391
          },
          "VARNAME_1": null
        }
      },
      ...
```

and would like to access the "dgai_violencia_domestica_2008_2014.Factor_amostra" property of each object, so as to encode a color value.

Is this possible with Leaflet+Omnivore, or would d3 or another library be needed?

A current, broken version of the map lives [here](http://www.audiovisualcode.net/tmp/dgai_vd_2009_2014/), with the relevant code being:

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = '...';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([39.5, -8.60], 7);

// Omnivore will AJAX-request this file behind the scenes and parse it:
// note that there are considerations:
// - The file must either be on the same domain as the page that requests it,
//   or both the server it is requested from and the user's browser must
//   support CORS.

// Internally this function uses the TopoJSON library to decode the given file
// into GeoJSON.

function getColor(d) {
    return d > 0.75 ? '#800026' :
           d > 0.50  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 0.25   ? '#FD8D3C' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
}

var pt = omnivore.topojson('dgai_violencia_domestica_2008_2014.topo.json');

function style(geometry) {
  return {
    fillColor: getColor(geometry.properties.dgai_violencia_domestica_2008_2014.Peso_na_duracao_da_amostra),
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 1
};
}

pt.setStyle(style);
pt.addTo(map);
```

A nudge in the right direction, anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some testing and as it turns out, the setStyle function won't execute:

```
pt.setStyle(function (feature) {
    console.log('Yay, i am executed!');
    return {
        'color': 'red'
    }
});
```

Using that `Yay, i am executed!` never gets logged to the console. Which made me suspect that there's something wrong with the `setStyle` method of Omnivore. So i tried it with a custom layer:

```
var geojson = new L.GeoJSON(null);

var pt = omnivore.topojson(url, null, geojson).addTo(map);

geojson.setStyle(function (feature) {
    console.log('Yay, i am executed!');
    return {
        'color': 'red'
    };
});
```

Same thing, `Yay, i am executed!` never get logged to the console. One thing left to try was the `style` option of `L.GeoJSON`:

```
var geojson = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
    'style': function (feature) {
        console.log('Yay, i am executed!');
        return {
            'color': 'red'
        };
    }
});

var pt = omnivore.topojson(url, null, geojson).addTo(map);
```

And lo and behold, that does what it's supposed to do. So i tried it with your style and color function and dataset:

```
function getColor(d) {
    return d > 0.75 ? '#800026' :
           d > 0.50 ? '#FC4E2A' :
           d > 0.25 ? '#FD8D3C' :
                      '#FFEDA0';
}

function getStyle (feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.dgai_violencia_domestica_2008_2014.Peso_na_duracao_da_amostra),
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 1
    };
}

var geojson = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
    'style': getStyle
});

var pt = omnivore.topojson(url, null, geojson).addTo(map);
```

This gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Peso_na_duracao_da_amostra' of undefined

That's because on the third feature, that property is missing. So your dataset is corrupt or incomplete. Hopefully this will help you along, good luck, here's a Plunker of my experiment which works (so far):

http://plnkr.co/edit/P6t96hTaOgSxTc4TPUuV?p=preview

Comment: That did it. I wrote a Processing sketch to gather all the lines in the original dataset referring to districts into json objects and then matched those to the names in the TopoJSON file. as it stands, the name matching isn't robust enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Look into using topojson.js as it converts GeometryCollection back to FeatureCollection so you can use the features.properties keys. I haven't done this since I'm currently trying to figure it out on my end.